# Injecting IHostingEnvironment into a Web API 2 controller

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to inject an `IHostingEnvironment` into my Web API 2 controller like this:

```
public class ClaimsController : BaseApiController
{
    private IConfigurationRoot config;

    public ClaimsController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        this.config = builder.Build();
    }
    //..other methods/actions
}
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
ExceptionMessage=An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ClaimsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

So I thought maybe I could use parameter injection but for the life of me I can't find any information on the world wide interweb to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Show your `Startup.cs`

Comment: Don't have one of those

Comment: What version of web api? Tags say web api 2 but `IHostingEnvironment` is from Asp.net core. `IConfigurationRoot ` is suppose to be in Startup not directly in controller.

Comment: Yes I am using Web API 2, but importing various bits from core. Is this the wrong thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit old, but maybe someone use it...
You can use ASP.NET core 2.0. There you don't have to even modify Startup.cs. You only need to inject it with constructor.

```
public class ClaimsController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public ClaimsController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
    //..other methods/actions
}
```

Be careful:

```
_env.WebRootPath
```

can be null if you haven't got directory wwwroot in your project.